# Windows 8 Screen Resolution in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a display mode to a VirtualBox VM?](https://superuser.com/questions/451962/how-to-add-a-display-mode-to-a-virtualbox-vm)

I am using VirtualBox to run windows 8 while I test it out.  All of my other virtual machines (i.e. Windows XP a Ubuntu) will use the full screen.  For some reason I am unable to get it to fit the full screen like it should.  The monitor I am using has its screen resolution set to 1600 X 900.

In the below screenshot of my XP virtual machine you can see the resolution is 1600 X 836.  Which utilizes the entire screen.
[image]

Now looking at the resolution settings in my Windows 8 virtual machine I do not have any resolution setting that is close enough to 1600 X 900.  How can I get a resolution setting in the Windows 8 virtual machine that will use the monitors entire area without causing scroll bars?

[image]

**EDIT**
Under the view toolbar in VirtualBox I selected ***Switch to Seemless Mode*** just to trouble shoot a little and then exited that mode.  Now it is actually auto resizing the screen.  However I am unable to get to the start ribbon or whatever it is called that appears on the right hand side of the screen.  So, I restarted the machine and now it is really slow.  Does VirtualBox have problems with guest additions working in Windows 8?

**EDIT ROUND 2**
Well, I un-installed and re-installed VirtualBox (the most current version).  I then created the Windows 8 virtual machine again from scratch.  I installed guest additions and it still is **not** working correctly.  I have virtual machines for Windows XP, Ubuntu, Fedora, and Xubuntu and they are all working flawlessly.  So far, Windows 8 has not impressed.

Comment: What's your host OS?  Are you using the latest VirtualBox version?  Did you install the VirtualBox Guest Additions?

Comment: I am running VirtualBox on Window 7 and I do have the latest version installed.  I also have guest additions installed.

Comment: I'm getting the same bad behavior. Also, dual monitors isn't working. I have a feeling the Windows 8 Guest Additions are half-baked right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something to try (assuming a Windows host):

- Stop VirtualBox (all VMs).
- Open a commnad prompt and navigate to your VirtualBox folder (something like "c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\").
- Run `VBoxManage.exe setextradata "Your VM Name" CustomVideoMode1 1600x900x32`
- Restart your Win8 VM and check to see if the resolution is available.

More info [here](http://www.mstechpages.com/2011/09/17/set-custom-resolution-in-virtualbox-for-windows-8/) and [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/114144407910978440348/posts/38EYCKyyh5W#114144407910978440348/posts/38EYCKyyh5W)

Comment: I did end up re-installing the windows 8 VirtualBox machine.  I added the resolution like you explained and it is working good.  For some reason guest additions just was not working.  Guest additions made it very buggy.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you haven't installed the **[VBox Guest additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html)**.
Once that is installed, it should scale to any resolution automatically.

[image: Guest additions]

Do remember to **restart your VM** after installation.

Comment: I do have guest additions installed and it is not auto resizing the desktop properly.

Comment: @Linger Try a reinstallation. Also, are you using a version of Virtualbox that gave you `Windows 8` as an option during VM creation?

Comment: Yes I am using a version of Virtualbox that gave you Windows 8 as an option during VM creation.

Comment: Try a reinstallation of Guest additions. Also ensure that `Auto-resize` display is checked in VBox.